# $ Is not defined - Uncaught referenceerror

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So, I know that this question has been asked before, but all the questions that I've seen, the jquery has been loaded after any other JS file. In my case it's different.

I am loading Jquery-1.11.2.min.js from my javascript file, and then loading the page's individual file, and for some reason, I'm getting the error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
```

My scripts are being called as follows:

```
<script async type="text/javascript" src="resources/javascript/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script async type="text/javascript" src="resources/javascript/'.$fileName.'.js"></script>
```

For some reason, the error is arising. What can I do to resolve my issue?

Comment: Are you *sure* jQuery has been loaded? Did you check what response you get when attempting to load the file? In which line does the error originate from in your JS file?

Comment: Don't load jQuery with `async`?

Comment: Loading your scripts asynchronously means that your jQuery might get loaded last.

Comment: Can you clarify what languages are you using? So far it seems a mix of html/javascript + php. What if $fileName? Is it still the scope of Javascript?

Comment: Yea, '.$fileName.' is php, sorry about that. HTML, JS and php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's highly likely that those `async` attributes are the cause of your problem. Loading order is not guaranteed when you mark a script as `async`, and given that jQuery is rather large, it's probably loading *after* your script tries to run.

[This article](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/script-loading/) discusses the ins and outs of script loading, but the simplest solution that it provides is to use ordinary, non-async `script` elements, and put them right before your closing `</body>` tag:

```
  ....
  <script src="resources/javascript/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="resources/javascript/'.$fileName.'.js"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your script in a load handler. It will ensure jquery is loaded before it executes.

```
window.addEventListener("load", function(){...});
```